# Is there a way to search for all classes that have more than a specified number of constructors?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a workspace with a large number of collaborative projects and a larger number of classes.

Let's say I want to do some cleanup in the classes and check which ones have too many constructors and would benefit from having a builder.

I'd like to do a search in Eclipse for the classes that have more than, for example, 3 constructors.
How could I do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to say multiple constructors or too many parameters in a constructor? Also it may not be supported by eclipse and you probably have to do this by hand.

Comment: Use something like https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections and write your own logic to find constructors with > N parameters

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 the most common issue is multiple constructors with cascading parameters

Comment: Reflection is the right way to go but `ronmamo/reflections` is somehow abandoned because the owner doesn't respond anymore. You should use [github.com/aschoerk/reflections8](https://github.com/aschoerk/reflections8).

Comment: Thanks, @fuggerjaki61, I'll add this as the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it appears that using reflection is the right way to do this.

Check this lib (link provided by @fuggerjaki61): https://github.com/aschoerk/reflections8